# Microsoft Webdeploy package not setting site root to application root

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, iis-8, webdeploy

I have an ASP.net AngularJS application. The site structure is:

Default Website

-> MyNewSite

->-> index.html

->-> other folders within site

My index.html file is being read, but all the files that it links to are not.
For instance:
index.html is being loaded (taken from Chrome developer tools - network tab)

192.168.0.1/mysite/

But

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

is failing as:

192.168.0.1/bower_components/angular/angular.js

Note the missing - /mysite/ part!

I'm using Visual Studio, previously I've been testing locally and with Azure without any issues, but now I'm trying to deploy on a Windows Server 2008r2 IIS8 and I'm getting this.

Anyone have any ideas as to whats going on?

Comment: your path is wrong try this `<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>`
Path is depend on where you add bower_components in your project hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of messing around, this wasn't due to a path issue. It was due to the version of IIS that I was trying to install the application to.

I was trying to install the application to IIS7. But for some reason it would run without issues on IIS8 and above. Other issues that I was running into were problems with PUT requests being denied.

So the resolution was, use a later version of IIS.